# How can I set a start date to this js timeline?

Tags: javascript

So I have this code that I am trying work with that sets up a horizontal timeline that I am currently using to showcase the weeks events on a website. However, the calendar always reverts back to the date of the event that comes first in the calendar. Which would be fine but we want to keep up the old events as well.

What I am needing help with is how to modify the code so that it will start on the event that is today's date instead of starting on the date that comes first in the calendar, or the oldest date in the list.

Here is the js file (named res-timeline.js)

```
(function($){
$.fn.jflatTimeline = function(options){

    /**------------------ SETTING PARAMETERS ------------------**/

    var timelinedates = new Array();
    var date_sort_asc = function (date1, date2) {
        // This is a comparison function that will result in dates being sorted in
        // ASCENDING order. As you can see, JavaScript's native comparison operators
        // can be used to compare dates. This was news to me.
        if (date1 > date2) return -1;
        if (date1 < date2) return 1;
        return 0;
    };

    var current_year = 0;
    var current_month = 0;
    var scroll_count = 2;
    var scrolled = 0;
    var scroll_time = 500;

    var month=new Array();
    month[0]="January";
    month[1]="February";
    month[2]="March";
    month[3]="April";
    month[4]="May";
    month[5]="June";
    month[6]="July";
    month[7]="August";
    month[8]="September";
    month[9]="October";
    month[10]="November";
    month[11]="December";

    var config = {};
    if(options){
        $.extend(config, options);
    }


    /**------------------ BEGIN FUNCTION BODY ------------------**/

    return this.each(function(){
        selector = $(this);

        if(options.scroll)
            scroll_count = parseInt(options.scroll);

        if(options.width)
            selector.css('width', options.width)

        if(options.scrollingTime)
            scroll_time = options.scrollingTime;

    /**------------------ INSERT  YEAR MONTH BAR------------------**/

        //
        if(!selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event.selected').length)
            selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event:first-child').addClass('selected')
        //This store the selected year to 'current_year'

        current_year = (new Date(selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event.selected').attr('data-date'))).getFullYear() 
        //This store the selected year to 'current_month'
        current_month = (new Date(selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event.selected').attr('data-date'))).getMonth()

        //This will generate the month-year bar if it doesn't exist + put the current year and month
        if(!selector.children('.month-year-bar').length){
            selector.prepend('<div class = "month-year-bar"></div>')
            selector.children('.month-year-bar').prepend('<div class = "year"><a class = "prev"><i class = "fa fa-angle-left"></i></a><span>' + String(current_year) + '</span><a class = "next"><i class = "fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div>')
            selector.children('.month-year-bar').prepend('<div class = "month"><a class = "prev"><i class = "fa fa-angle-left"></i></a><span>' + String(month[current_month]) + '</span><a class = "next"><i class = "fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div>')
        }

    /**------------------ STORING DATES INTO ARRAY------------------**/

        var i = 0;
        // Store the dates into timelinedates[]
        selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event').each(function(){
            timelinedates[i] = new Date($(this).attr('data-date'));
            i++;
        })
        //Sort the dates from small to large
        timelinedates.sort(date_sort_asc)

    /**------------------ INSERT DATES BAR------------------**/

        //This will insert the month year bar


        if(!selector.children(".dates-bar").length)
            selector.children(".month-year-bar").after('<div class = "dates-bar"><a class = "prev"><i class = "fa fa-angle-left"></i></a><a class = "noevent">No event found</a><a class = "next"><i class = "fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></div>')

        //This for loop will insert all the dates in the bar fetching from timelinedates[]
        for(i=0; i < timelinedates.length; i++){
            dateString = String((timelinedates[i].getMonth() + 1) + "/" + timelinedates[i].getDate() + "/" + timelinedates[i].getFullYear())
            if(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a[data-date = "'+ dateString +'"]').length)
                continue;
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.prev').after('<a data-date = '+ dateString + '><span class = "date">' + String(timelinedates[i].getDate()) + '</span><span class = "month">' + String(month[timelinedates[i].getMonth()]) + '</span></a>')
        }

        //This will convert the event data-date attribute from mm/dd/yyyy into m/d/yyyy
        for(i = 0; i < selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event').length; i++){
            var a = new Date(selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event:nth-child(' + String(i+1)+ ')').attr('data-date'))
            dateString = String((a.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + a.getDate() + "/" + a.getFullYear())
            selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event:nth-child(' + String(i+1)+ ')').attr('data-date', dateString)
        }


        //This will hide the noevent bar
        selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').each(function(){
            if((new Date($(this).attr('data-date'))).getFullYear() != current_year)
                $(this).hide();
        })

        //Prevent from calling twice
        if(selector.hasClass('calledOnce'))
            return 0;
        selector.addClass('calledOnce')

        //Add 'selected' class the date
        selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a[data-date ="' + String(selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event.selected').attr('data-date')) + '"]').addClass('selected')
        //Adding Class s_screen
        if(selector.width() < 500)
            selector.addClass('s_screen')

        $(window).resize(function(){
            if(selector.width() < 500)
                selector.addClass('s_screen')
            else
                selector.removeClass('s_screen')    
        })
    /**------------------ EVENTS HANDLING------------------**/

    /**------------------ EVENTS FOR CLICKING ON THE DATES ------------------**/

        selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').click(function(){
            a = String($(this).attr('data-date'));

            selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event.selected').removeClass('selected');

            selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event[data-date="' + a + '"]').addClass('selected');

            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected')

        })

    /**------------------ EVENTS FOR CLICKING TO THE NEXT DATE EVENT ------------------**/

        selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.next').click(function(){
            var actual_scroll = scroll_count;
            var c = selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible()').length
            if(scrolled + scroll_count >= c)
                actual_scroll = (c - scrolled)-1

            if(parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'))*actual_scroll > selector.children('.dates-bar').width())
                while(parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'))*actual_scroll > selector.children('.dates-bar').width() && actual_scroll > 1)
                    actual_scroll -= 1;

            var a = (-1)*actual_scroll*parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'));
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').animate({marginLeft: '+=' + String(a)+ 'px'}, scroll_time)
            scrolled += actual_scroll;

            current_month = new Date(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(' + String(scrolled) + ')').attr('data-date')).getMonth()

            selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('span').text(month[current_month])
        })


    /**------------------ EVENTS FOR CLICKING TO THE PREVIOUS DATE EVENT ------------------**/


        selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.prev').click(function(){
            var actual_scroll = scroll_count;
            var c = selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible()').length
            if(scrolled <= scroll_count)
                actual_scroll = scrolled;

            if(parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'))*actual_scroll > selector.children('.dates-bar').width())
                while(parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'))*actual_scroll > selector.children('.dates-bar').width() && actual_scroll > 1)
                    actual_scroll -= 1;


            var a = actual_scroll*parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'));
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').animate({marginLeft: '+=' + String(a)+ 'px'}, scroll_time)
            scrolled -= actual_scroll;

            current_month = new Date(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(' + String(scrolled) + ')').attr('data-date')).getMonth()

            selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('span').text(month[current_month])
        })


    /**------------------ EVENTS FOR CLICKING TO THE NEXT MONTH ------------------**/

        selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('.next').click(function(){

            if(!(current_month == 11))
                current_month += 1;
            else
                current_month = 0;

            var month_found = 0;

            selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('span').text(month[current_month])
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible()').each(function(){
                    month_found += 1 ;
                if((new Date($(this).attr('data-date'))).getMonth() >= current_month){
                    return false;
                }
            })


            var a = (month_found-scrolled-1)*parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'));
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').animate({marginLeft: '-=' + String(a)+ 'px'}, scroll_time)
            scrolled = month_found - 1;

        })          

    /**------------------ EVENTS FOR CLICKING TO THE PREVIOUS MONTH ------------------**/


        selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('.prev').click(function(){
            if(!(current_month == 0))
                current_month -= 1;
            else
                current_month = 11;

            var month_found = 0;

            selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('span').text(month[current_month])
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible()').each(function(){
                    month_found += 1 ;
                if((new Date($(this).attr('data-date'))).getMonth() >= current_month){
                    return false;
                }
            })


            var a = (month_found-scrolled-1)*parseInt(selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').css('width'));
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible():eq(0)').animate({marginLeft: '-=' + String(a)+ 'px'}, scroll_time)
            scrolled = month_found - 1;


        })


    /**------------------ EVENTS FOR CLICKING TO THE NEXT YEAR ------------------**/

        selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.year').children('.next').click(function(){
            current_year += 1;
            selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.year').children('span').text(String(current_year))

            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').each(function(){

                if((new Date($(this).attr('data-date'))).getFullYear() != current_year)
                    $(this).hide();
                else
                    $(this).show()
            })

            if(!selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible').length){
                selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.noevent').css('display', 'block');
            }else{
                selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.noevent').css('display', 'none');
                selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').css('margin-left', '0');
                scrolled = 0;
                selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event').removeClass('selected');
                selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event').each(function(){
                    a = (new Date($(this).attr('data-date')))
                    if(a.getFullYear() == current_year){
                        $(this).addClass('selected')
                        current_month = a.getMonth();
                        selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('span').text(month[current_month])
                        return false;
                    }
                })
            }
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').removeClass('selected');
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a[data-date ="' + String(selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event.selected').attr('data-date')) + '"]').addClass('selected')

        })


    /**------------------ EVENTS FOR CLICKING TO THE PREVIOUS YEAR ------------------**/


        selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.year').children('.prev').click(function(){
            current_year -= 1;
            selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.year').children('span').text(String(current_year))

            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').each(function(){

                if((new Date($(this).attr('data-date'))).getFullYear() != current_year)
                    $(this).hide();
                else
                    $(this).show()

                if(!selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent):visible').length){
                    selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.noevent').css('display', 'block');
                }else{
                    selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a.noevent').css('display', 'none');                   
                    selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').css('margin-left', '0');
                    scrolled = 0;
                    selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event').removeClass('selected');
                    selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event').each(function(){
                        a = (new Date($(this).attr('data-date')))
                        if(a.getFullYear() == current_year){
                            $(this).addClass('selected')
                            current_month = a.getMonth();
                            selector.children('.month-year-bar').children('.month').children('span').text(month[current_month])
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a:not(.prev, .next, .noevent)').removeClass('selected');
                        selector.children('.dates-bar').children('a[data-date ="' + String(selector.children('.timeline-wrap').children('.event.selected').attr('data-date')) + '"]').addClass('selected')

        })

    })
}
```

And the code for the html

```
$(function() {
$(".DateDiv").each(function(index) {
    var sRange = $(this).find(".DateRange").html();
    var arrTemp = sRange.split(" to ");
    var dtFrom = new Date(arrTemp[0]);
    var dtTo = new Date(arrTemp[1]);
    var dtNow = new Date();
    if (dtNow >= dtFrom && dtNow <= dtTo)
        $(this).show();
});
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] using the snippet editor?

Comment: Tried, but the snippet would be too large...

Comment: Your code is already too large. Make a MINIMAL version